# How to find memory usage per so library?

Tags: android, android-library, shared-libraries, android-memory

I am loading two shared libraries (third-party) in my application. I need to check the memory-footprint of each library and based on that, decide which one to finally go with.

Is there any way I can see the exact memory usage by each of these two so libs ?

P.S. I looked around on SO but could not find answer to this specific question.